Altium coplanar waveguide ground clearance rules
I am trying to route 50 Ohm coplanar waveguides in Altium for some 2.45GHz circuits. I have defined my stackup and impedance requirements via the layer stackup manager / impedance calculator, and have updated my design rules to enforce the trace width as defined by the impedance profiles.
My question is this - do I also need to define clearance rules for ground polygon pours around the trace? According to this documentation about controlled impedance routing it suggests that I do, but when I look at content on youtube from Altium Academy, they seem to suggest that those clearances should be handled automatically. I just want to ensure I am using the tool correctly and am not shooting myself in the foot.



This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).
